# How does Intel SGX bind the Host application process and the enclave to each other?

Tags: linux, intel, sgx

How does Intel SGX bind the Host application process and the enclave to each other? That is, how to ensure that the process that calls EENTER to enter the enclave is the correct process. If process A creates enclave 1 and process B creates enclave 2, how does SGX ensure that process A cannot enter enclave 2 for execution?